# how to locate the react ocassionally render issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am listening the reducer conversation data in function component which was fetched data from server side in react 18 like this:

```
const { conversations } = useSelector((state: any) => state.conversation);
```

when recieved the conversation data, update the react page state like this:

```
const [loadedConversations, setLoadedConversations] = useState<Map<number, IConversation>>(new Map<number, IConversation>());

React.useEffect(() => {
    if (conversations && Object.keys(conversations).length > 0) {
        const legacyConverstions = loadedConversations;
        conversations.list.forEach((item: IConversation) => {
            if (!legacyConverstions.has(item.id)) {
                legacyConverstions.set(item.id, item);
            }
        });
        setLoadedConversations(legacyConverstions);
    }
}, [conversations]);
```

when the page state changed, will trigger the render function to refresh the UI, the render function look like this:

```
const conversationRender = () => {
        if (loadedConversations === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        if (BaseMethods.isNull(loadedConversations)) {
            return;
        }
        const conversationList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        loadedConversations.forEach((value, key) => {
            conversationList.push(
                <div key={uuid()} onClick={() => handleConversation(key)} className="conversation-item">
                    <img src={chatPic}></img>
                    <span title={value.title.toString()}>{value.title}</span>
                    <div className="conversation-item-icon"><DeleteOutlined onClick={() => delConversations(key)}></DeleteOutlined></div>
                </div>);
        });
        if (loadedConversations.size > 9) {
            conversationList.push(<button onClick={loadMoreConversations}>Load more...</button>);
        }
        return conversationList;
    }
```

everything seems work fine, but now I am facing a issue that the conversation list render success occassionally when refresh page, sometimes render normal, sometimes render null list(I am sure every time the server send the conversation list successfully, the server will never send a null list source data). I am debugging again and again, no error output in console. How to locate the occassion render issue? any suggestion? BTW, the render works fine in develop environment, but occassionally failed in production. I have already searched from google and ask chatgpt but did not found any clue.